# Examples of modal fallacies , particularly in mathematics.

Tags: logic, fake-proofs

Here https://www.sfu.ca/~swartz/modal_fallacy.htm Pr Norman Swartz , author of " Possible Worlds: An Introduction To Logic And Its Philosophy" gives philosophically interesting examples of modal fallacies.

Can you think of other interesting examples?

Are there classic examples of modal fallacies in scientific thought, particulary in mathematics?

Incidentally, do modal notions have " the right of the city" in mathematics?

---

By a modal fallacy, I mean a fallacy implying modal notions such as " necessity", " possibility", " contingency".

For example:

(1) Necessarily, I will recover or I will die of this disease. 
(2) So, taking a medecine is pointless, for whatever I may do, I will recover necessarily or die necessarily.

OR

(1) What is true cannot be false. 
(2) It is true that Kennedy has been assassinated. 
(3) Therefore, it could not have benn the case Kennedy not to be assassinated, Kennedy's dead was inevitable.

Comment: Strange ! Would you NOT take your medicine because if you die because of that it would have been inevitable ? With this strange philosophy, you could also cross a street blind because it would anyway happen what "someone" has planned.

Comment: Peter. Your crossing the street example is exactly what modal fallacy leads to: this is called logical fatalism. Note I said clearly it is a fallacy.

Comment: And you search such a fallacy in mathematics ?

Comment: I wonder whether logical mistakes involving modal notions can occur in mathematics, or , more broadly, in scientific thought.

Comment: I would say neurobiology is such an example. I am not aware of an example in mathematics.

Comment: The difficulty with finding mathematical examples is that modality, as such, isn't really a part of mathematical reasoning. But sometimes people do use modal logics to reason about other mathematical objects (like provability logic), and you could potentially express common misconceptions about those objects in modal terms. The snag there is they may not be very easy to understand if you're not a mathematician.